# How to Improve this design, make people understand Accuracy?

Tags: design, info-visualisation, ipad

I have a rough design for a progress report, primarily to be shown on the iPad.

This is supposed to show what the kid is good at, and what the kid is not good at.

Feedback I've received:

- It's not easy to make out that the number in the circles is Accuracy

Can someone suggest how to improve this and communicate what the values in the circle actually mean (or show it in an alternative way)?

[image]

Comment: two suggestions: turn your circles into rounded rectangles and increase the contrast. maybe for the green ones black text will work better. bold text might also help legibility there. secondly, at the bottom use the space you have better. the text is tiny and lost in lots of space. Maybe some colours in the margins and headers would help as well. not sure if this question is more suitable for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE!  I wanted to share some feedback on your question: site reviews are off topic as the scope of answers will not be generally relevant to anyone other than the original poster.  I would recommend rephrasing the question to focus on the primary usability question I see, which is how to communicate the values in the circles.  The second portion of the question--the UI being too "old school"--is very broad and subjective, so it would not fit within the mission of this SE without being improved.

Comment: @TheUser1024 thanks for the feedback - I'll try it out.

Comment: @CharlesWesley - thanks for the comment, I'll try to edit the question and make it more appropriate.

Comment: Instead of showing percentage, have you considered showing letter grades.  90% or above A, 80% - 89% B, etc.  I think everyone would understand letter grades.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow thanks for that suggestion, I will try it out.

Comment: It seems the number is more important than the circle. Will everything in the left always be green and everything on the right always red? If so, then the dots are somewhat redundant and are probably getting in the way rather than helping.

Comment: @DA01 actually yes - everything in the left will be green and everything in the right will be shades of red (orange for say 50%, red for 30%). But I wanted some visual way to reinforce this segregation - how can I do that without these colored circles?

Comment: Unless your grading system works in a non precise way, like "vg - very good", "g - good", "a - average", "b - bad", don't use letters, numbers are precise, letters are not.

Comment: @PatomaS ok. That idea got shot down by my team mates too, for the exact same reason; it will be confusing to understand what each letters mean, and we will need a reference, which is just too much work for the user.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try visually showing their progress?

Also, the color of the bars can change as the progress changes, RED= 10-35% Orange=36-70% Green=70%-100%.
[image]

Comment: because it is not progress - it is accuracy. I had tried to mix the progress and accuracy thing in a previous iteration (length of the bar shows progress, color shows accuracy) but people just got confused with that.

Answer (score 2):

You're focusing heavily on the word "accuracy", but you're discussing the topic of skills.  In an educational setting, the word "proficiency" better represents the goals of teaching, and teachers often measure proficiency by reporting the students' accuracy on tests.  I would try to use the more appropriate word, as it will help reduce confusion.

Also, progress is an appropriate metaphor when teaching.  An accuracy test is a single-point-in-time measurement, but progress is measurements over time.  Even when you're reporting on the scores for a single test, it's part of the overall journey towards mastery.

As far as a confusing display, I agree.  The colored circles are static and do not indicate anything.  Your groupings aren't really ordered or complete.

Consider a display like this:

```
           Skills                     Proficiency

        1 digit              Needs improvement | Mastered
    multiplication          0%    25%    50%   |75%      100%
        Tables of 1   90%  [                   |       X   ]
        Tables of 2   80%  [                   |   X       ]
        Tables of 3   85%  [                   |     X     ]
        Tables of 4   92%  [                   |        X  ]
        Tables of 5    0%  [X                  |           ]
        Tables of 6   30%  [         X         |           ]
        Tables of 7   50%  [              X    |           ]
        Tables of 8    0%  [X                  |           ]
        Tables of 9    0%  [X                  |           ]
```

You could still use colors to highlight the skills that need improvement.  But this solves some of your problems of ordering, grouping, while still indicating whether or not the students have achieved mastery.

Comment: my worry with "proficiency" is that it will be confusing - "Accuracy" is a lot more clearer as it has more consistent meaning (x correct out of total y in percentage). But I get your point; need to think about how to represent this data better.

Answer (score 1):

Why not order skills by accuracy? Order shows the pattern.

[image: pic]

Comment: I don't think you've really understood the question here. Or if you have you've not really explained yourself very well. the issue OP has is that users don't understand that this is Accuracy that is being reflected. How does your example manage those expectations?

Comment: Actually, at first look I thought the same (that this doesn't solve my problem) but I think the heading added above might just help clarify it a bit - so in that way, it is something I could try out. Thanks!

Comment: Just clarifying - the order makes it look difficult to understand the skills, but I like the simple idea of showing accuracy above in the column name.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there isn't much context to the percentages that are presented. What are they percentages of?

For example: "Skills to be improved - Subtract within 20: 30%". 30% what? If it's supposed to be Accuracy, it's not called out or made apparent anywhere. You could call it out or simplify the concept a bit.